# solicitar datos al modelo desde el controlador asp.net mvc c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estoy iniciando un desarrollo en asp.net MVC C#.

Lo que necesito saber es cómo puedo, desde el controlador, llamar a una subrutina del modelo. La idea es pasarle como parámetro una clave, y que ésta me regerese la descripción correspondiente que se encuentra en una base de datos.

La consulta a la base la efectúo con `sqlcommand`.

Ya creé una clase public (`public class buscadato`) pero no hace nada, no sé qué estoy haciendo mal o qué me falta.

¿Me pueden proporcionar un ejemplo de cómo definir la clase y cómo llamarla desde el controlador para pasarle y regresar un string?

EN EL MODELO:
    public class buscarPais
    {
        public string WCVEPAI;
        public string WDESPAI;

```
    public buscarPais(string WDATO1, string WDATO2)
    {
        WCVEPAI = WDATO1;
        WDESPAI = WDATO2;
    }

    public string xbuscarPais()
    {
        WDESPAI = "x";
        string CONBD = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BDPROADIN"].ConnectionString;
        var BDCON = new SqlConnection(CONBD);
        BDCON.Open();

        var INSSQL = "SELECT * FROM COAPI WHERE CVEPAI = " + WCVEPAI;
        var CMDSQL = new SqlCommand(INSSQL, BDCON);
        SqlDataReader reader = CMDSQL.ExecuteReader();

        if (reader.Read())
        {
            WDESPAI = (string)reader["DesPai"];
        }
        else
        {
            WDESPAI = "No existe en catalogo.";
        }
        System.Console.WriteLine(WDESPAI);
        reader.Close();
        BDCON.Close();
        WDESPAI = "AB";
        return WDESPAI;
    }
}
}
```

EN EL CONTROLADOR:

```
                    CatPai BP = new CatPai();
                    buscarPais bp = new buscarPais(WCVEPAI,WDESPAI);
```

Comment: Hola @JCRH. ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]! ¿Podrías publicar el código que intentaste, por más que no funcione? Eso ayudaría significativamente a contextualizar tu pregunta y que no sea tan complicado entender la descripción. Quizás te sea útil leer [ask].

Comment: bienvenido al sitio, te recomiendo darle una visualización al workshop que hice hace unos meses sobre ASP.net MVC 5 + Entity Framework 6: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LZG76aLykY Saludos! PD: Edita tu pregunta con todo el código que estás intentando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hay múltiples maneras en que puedes realizar la llamada a esa función. Me imagino que lo que deseas es que se muestre ese valor en la vista por lo tanto podrías crear un modelo-vista:

```
public class BuscaPaisVM {
    public string Nombre {get;set;}
    //Otras propiedades que desees mostrar
}
```

Y se llamaría mas o menos así:

```
public ActionResult BuscarPais(string wdato1){
    string wdato1 = string.Empty;
    var bp = new buscarPais(WCVEPAI,WDESPAI);
    var _out = new BuscaPaisVM{ Nombre = bp.xbuscarPais(), /* Otras propiedades */ };
    return View(_out);
}
```

Otra posibilidad es que quieras llamar al método mediante Ajax. O sea, una vez cargada la página. Para eso no necesitas un modelo-vista y puedes hacer esto:

```
public ActionResult BuscarPais(string wdato1){
    var bp = new buscarPais(wdato1, string.Empty);
    return Json(bp.xbuscarPais());
}
```

Y, como dije, lo llamarías mediante un método Ajax en el HTML de tu vista.

Ahora, hay algunos problemas con tu clase buscarPais:

- Los miembros WCVEPAI y WDESPAI deberían ser propiedades
- El miembro WDESPAI me parece que no debería ser un miembro de la clase ya que no hacemos nada con ese miembro mas que asignarlo, pero el método xbuscarPais  lo devuelve como salida. Esto puede llegar a ser confuso. Sería mejor limitarse a devolver el valor en la función xbuscarPais o, mejor aún, crearlo como propiedad y llamar a xbuscarPais en su método Set.
- Al final de xbuscarPais estableces WDESPAI a un valor constante ("AB") por lo tanto deshaces todo lo que realizaste anteriormente.
- En xbuscarPais realizas un select * from. Sin embargo, sólo necesitas un campo de la base de datos: DesPai. Es importante acostumbrarse siempre a incluir todos los campos en una consulta de base de datos aunque el código sea corto. El uso de select * from debería limitarse sólo al editor de consultas.

Aquí una versión mejorada de la clase BuscarPais:

```
public static class BuscarPais { 
    public static string Buscar(string wvcepai)
    {
        string _out = "x";
        string CONBD = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BDPROADIN"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(CONBD))
        {
            conn.Open();

            var INSSQL = "SELECT DesPai FROM COAPI WHERE CVEPAI = @cvepai";
            var CMDSQL = new SqlCommand(INSSQL, conn);
            CMDSQL.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("cvepai", cvepai));
            using (SqlDataReader reader = CMDSQL.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (reader.Read())
                {
                    _out = (string)reader["DesPai"];
                }
                else
                {
                    _out = "No existe en catalogo.";
                }
                System.Console.WriteLine(_out);
                reader.Close();
            }
            conn.Close();
        }

        return _out;
    }
}
```

Para llamarlo sólo basta con lo siguiente:

```
string despais = BuscarPais.Buscar(WCVEPAI);
```

Comment: Buenas tardes Alexei, muchas gracias por responder y por la informacion que me das.

Answer (score 0):

Amigo si estas usando MVC C# puedes instanciar un modelo de tu base de datos en el proyecto y puedes hacer llamados y consultas con LINQ sin necesidad de utilizar ese tipo de comandos.

te recomiendo te leas un poco la documentación del MODELO VISTA CONTROLADOR para que puedas crear tu modelo y todas las consultas se te hagan mucho mas fácil.